# Is there a way to "view the code" of a MS Access file?

Tags: ms-access

I know it's crazy thing to think about but asking never hurts! I'v been always curious to know if there's any way to somehow view the code for MS Access like we can for Internet Explorer by selecting a "View Source"?

Specifically I'm super intrigued to know the Filtering feature. Thanks all!

Comment: If you have admin access to the file then yes you can view the code project.  If not and this is someone else's program then no, and that is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access is not open source last I knew, you could look at the code for [Calligra Kexi](http://www.calligra.org/kexi/), which is an OSS alternative to Access, they will presumably have filtering functionality.

The code can be found at http://community.kde.org/Calligra/Building#Getting_the_Source_Code